# iOS: How to rebuild the email-app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I have a database with a lot of private messages (PMs).
PMs can be stored in different folders, like Emails (send, inbox, folders) and so on.
To cut a long story short: I want to rebuild the iPhone Email-app for my private messages in my database, which I can get with a JSON query (wrapper is allready implemented and working perfect).

How to rebuild this?

Features I wanna have is PMs should be stored in a kind of cache on the iphone, so that user can read them without haveing internet.

Any idea, how to rebuild the design and how to add this cache functionality?

Comment: Your question is way too large. Please specify some things you cannot figure out.

Comment: It's only 2 little questions: What design elements I need for rebuild this app (tables etc.) and how I can add cache functionallity.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna answer those below =).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Design

The Mail.app uses a `UINavigationController` for navigating trough the several views.

- **Accounts-view:** `UITableViewController`.
- **Account-view:** `UITableViewController` showing an `UIToolbar`.
- **Mails-view:** `UITableViewController` showing an `UIToolbar`.
- **Mail-view:** `UIViewController` consisting of an `UIWebView` (which shows the actual mail) and an `UIToolbar`.

---

#### Caching

You should implement `NSCoding` to every class you write (so something like `KVMail`, `KVAccount`, etc.).
Then, when the 'database' has been changed, you save all the records in `NSUserDefaults`, like this:

```
NSArray *accounts;
    - KVAccount *someAccount;
        - NSArray *mails;
            - KVMail *mail;
            - KVMail *mail;
            - KVMail *mail;
```

Say your design looks like this (so an array of accounts, where every account consists of an array of mails).

When you implement `NSCoding` you can save the database like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:accounts] forKey:@"database"];
```

Now, when the user starts the app again, you can load it back into your RAM by doing this:

```
NSArray *accounts = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"database"]];
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Is there any limitation for the caching in iOS? So can I save unlimted PMs here? Is the NSUserDefaults with endless time and space?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` writes your data to `/Library/Preferences/` (FS). So you can write as much data as the device has storage for (eg. 16GB).